# Can i run two servers on different ports with the same websocket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm learning how to use Action Cable in Rails. I have small app with appearance system (green dot when the user is online) and i want to test it. I found that i can run two servers on two different ports with the same db, but can i run two servers with the same websocket server that i can see changes on from one client on second client without reloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using multiple browsers?

I would suggest you to use 2 browser windows 1 incognito and the other would be a normal one. And you can test the websocket with 2 users in real time.